# How do I build a ROS package?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting errors when I type make.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9039/how-do-i-build-a-ros-package?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use rosmake. It first builds all the package's dependencies, then builds the package itself.

E.g., to build the rviz package:

```
rosmake rviz
```

You can do this from anywhere. Alternatively, you can go to the package directory, then run rosmake with no arguments:

```
roscd rviz
rosmake
```

---

Originally posted by [mwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/28/mwise/) with karma: 208 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Packages have two kinds of dependencies: system dependencies, and other ROS packages.

For the system dependencies, you may need to run (for example):

```
rosdep install rviz
```

For the ROS package dependencies, run:

```
rosmake rviz
```

After you know the dependencies are up to date, **then** it's OK to run `make` in the package directory. That is faster during active package development.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also for package dependencies, especially those downloaded packages, its is useful to run

```
rosmake <package_name> --rosdep-install
```

Which then tries the much it can to fix dependencies based on the rosdep.yaml files

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1